# update laravel не могу обновить данные

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет помогите плиз

```
<form action="{{ route('searchprofile.update', $data->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="modal-profile">
@method('PATCH')
    <input type="text" value="{{ $data->name }}" name="name">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
</form>
```

Моя ошибка 
419
Page Expired

Мой контроллер

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    DB::table('search_profiles')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->update([
        'name' => $request->name,
    ]);

    return redirect(route('user.profile.index', $id));
}
```

Comment: @user340081 спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить поле с csrf токеном в форму

{{csrf_field()}} - в середину формы вставьте, и не будет ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой вид атак, который называется **Cross-Site Request Forgery** - [*Межсайтовая Подделка Запроса*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0).

Laravel предоставляет встроенный функционал для защиты от этой атаки - [CSRF-token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf)

Предполагается, что Вы должны для каждой формы, обработка которой изменяет каким-либо образом данные (включая добавления записи в БД), включать csrf-token.

В Laravel это работает следующим образом:

1) Существует два способа добавить csrf на страницу:

- `@csrf`-директива [blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade) шаблонизатора;
- если Вы не используете blade - глобальная функция `csrf_token()`.

2) В Laravel есть [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware) `VerifyCsrfToken`, который автоматически добавляется в настройках (`config/app.php` по-моему) на все [routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing) из группы web, который этот токен и проверяет.

3) Для [Ajax](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) запросов в Laravel [можно](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token):

- добавить в [meta-tag](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8) csrf-token
- добавлять его в [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/HTTP/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8) ajax-запроса

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

В Вашем случае Вам действительно нужно добавить в форму csrf-токен одним из описанных выше способов.

Или (не рекомендуется) [убрать Ваш url](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris) из проверки VerifyCsrfToken middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое)